# Laravel Gates using model and returns "Using $this when not in object context" Line 28 of AzureUser model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-gate

Im trying to create a Gate in Laravel. The idea is to check if one of the roles is present on an AzureAD access token.

So far I have this

```
Gate::define('admin_cml', function () {
   $roles = AzureUser::roles();
   return in_array(config('app-roles.cml_admin'),$roles);
});
```

So far the response is "Using $this when not in object context".

[image: Error of Gate and Model]

Here is the full code

**AuthServiceProvider** -> Path app\Providers

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use App\Models\AzureUser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Gate::define('admin_cml', function () {
            $roles = AzureUser::roles();
            return in_array(config('app-roles.cml_admin'),$roles);
        });
    }
}
```

**AzureUser Model** -> app\Models

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AzureUser extends Model
{
 
        protected $id_token;
        protected $access_token;
        protected $user;
    
        public function __construct($access_token, $id_token)
        {
            $this->access_token = $access_token;
            $this->id_token = $id_token;
    
            $this->user = Socialite::driver('azure-oauth')->userFromToken($access_token);
        }
    
        public function get()
        {
            return $this->user;
        }
    
        public function roles()
        {
            $tokens = explode('.', $this->id_token);
    
            return json_decode(static::urlsafeB64Decode($tokens[1]))->roles;
        }
    
        public static function urlsafeB64Decode($input)
        {
            $remainder = strlen($input) % 4;
    
            if ($remainder) {
                $padlen = 4 - $remainder;
                $input .= str_repeat('=', $padlen);
            }
    
            return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
        }
    
}
```

**Routes**

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\loginController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::check()){
        return redirect()->route('app');
    }
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::get('/app',function(){
    return view('layouts.app');
})->name('app')->middleware('auth');

// user routes
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', [loginController::class,'login'])->name('login');

    Route::get('/logout', [loginController::class,'logout'])->name('logout');
});

Route::group(['middelware'=>['auth'],'prefix'=>'adminmm','as'=>'adminmm.'],function () {
    Route::get('/carros', function(){
        return "carros";
    })->name('carros');

    Route::get('/companias', function(){
        return "companias";
    })->name('companias');
});

// Here is the error. When going to admincml/mecanicos is when the error is showing up
Route::group(['middelware'=>['auth'],'prefix'=>'admincml','as'=>'admincml.'],function () {
    Route::get('/mecanicos', function(){
        if (! Gate::allows('admin_cml')) {
            abort(403);
        }
        return "mecanicos";
    })->name('mecanicos');
});
```

Any ideas why is not detecting the model?
Thanks!

Comment: show whats in `roles`

Comment: is the model in the correct folder? does it have the right namespace declared? does it have the correct filename and class name? are there any errors in this class file that would stop it from being loaded? did you run `composer dump` just to make sure the autoloader is functioning properly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @lagbox. I did have a few typos and are fixed. Now I have an issue that is "Using $this when not in object context". I have updated the question with the AzureUser model and the new AuthServiceProvider.

Comment: @bhucho. I just added the AzureUser model that contains the roles function. Also, the error now is different since I had a typo error

Comment: np ... btw, that doesn't look like an eloquent model (doesn't seem to have any reason to extend from `Model`) ... what line is throwing this new error?

Comment: @lagbox. The error is showing up when I call the route. The route has a Gate that is the one defined there. The route is on the post. Only when calling the route is the error. The rest is working fine.

Comment: show the line that is causing the error in the title of this question ... the error message comes with the line that causes it

Comment: Just added the routes. The problem is commented on the routes code.

Comment: that isn't the line causing the error, it might be down the stack chain but that isn't the line causing that error message .... side note: it is `middleware` not `middelware`

Comment: Just added the error picture and the line in the title. sorry for the delay with that. And thanks for the heads up on the typo!

Comment: this `AzureUser` isn't an Eloquent model ... you are statically calling a method that isn't static so that is a problem, you would need to get an instance of that class and then call that method on it, but not sure where you would be getting the data to pass as the arguments to the constructor of it though

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from AuthServiceProvider where you use static call to method, but it's not a static one...

```
AzureUser::roles();
```

It appears that you want to use $this instance variable there, so you have
to make an instance to it like this in AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
use App\AzureUser;

$azure = new AzureUser();
$roles = $azure->role();
```